# How to send an image via POST request in Flask

Tags: python, numpy, flask, python-requests

I am trying to send an image from 1 `Flask` app to another i.e. from 1 endpoint to another, but I don't know what conversion needs to be done so that it can be sent and received properly. I am using the below code but I am getting `NoneType` object at the receiver side

**Sender Flask App Code**

```
import requests

data = {}
data['image'] = # <image> 
res = requests.post('http://<IP>:<PORT>/', data = data)
```

**Receiver Flask App Code**

```
from flask import request
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

f1 = request.form.get('image')
print(type(f1))

f2 = np.fromstring(f1, np.uint8)
print(type(f2), f2.shape)

f3 = cv.imdecode(f2, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
print(type(f3))
```

I have tried sending 2 types of images. Sending image of type `<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>` prodcues following output at receiver side

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (62,)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Sending image of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` prodcues following output at receiver side

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (3,)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: data['image'] = # <image> . What you passed here? The path?

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan Image of type `<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>` and `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Try this. data['image'] = open('your_image.jpg', 'rb')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the image with `requests.post(url, files={'image': open('image.jpg', 'rb')})`, see https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file.

Receive the image with `file = request.files['image']` and e.g. store it with `file.save('image.jpg')`.